# Issue Keeping Correct Value

Tags: jquery

Below I have included a small snippet of a inventory/production database that I am trying to build. The HTML table on my actual site will be pulled from a database table.

As you can see in the jQuery you are able to click on a square and it becomes editable.  Once an edit is made (click to another `td` or sit on the edited one without typing for 2.5 seconds) ajax pushes the change back out to the database.  When I push the new value out to the database

I must also push the old value because math functions are done to the value and subtracted out of multiple tables before the same math functions are done to the new value and added into those same tables (in short, subtracting out old info and then adding in new).

**My Question:** My current way of recording the old value doesnt work if the user clicks between `td` cells too quickly editing values.  I am hoping someone can help me come up with better logic to always have the correct "old value".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var old;

  $('td').click(function() {
    
    if ($(this).data().old === undefined) {
      $(this).data({ old: $(this).text() });
    }
    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
    
  });

  var saveTimeout;
  
  // Remove the "saved" class on keydown
  $('td').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("saved");
  });

  $('td').on('input blur', function(e) {

    var timeoutDelay = 2500;
    if (e.type == "blur") {
      timeoutDelay = 1;
    }

    // If NOT already saved...
    if (!$(this).hasClass("saved")) {
      
      var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here
      // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
      _this.addClass("saved");

      clearTimeout(_this.data('saveTimeout'));
      _this.data('saveTimeout', setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Saving " + _this.text()) + "...";
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "updatedatabase.php",
            data: {
              content: _this.text(),
              date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
              prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
              old: _this.data().old
            }
          })
          .done(function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
          });

        toastr.options = {
          "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
          "onclick": null,
          "timeOut": "2500",
        }
        
        toastr.info(_this.data('old'),'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');
                
        _this.data({});
        
        _this.prop('contenteditable', false);

      }, timeoutDelay));
    }
  });

  $("td").hover(function() {

    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');
    $('tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').addClass('highlight');

  }, function() {

    $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');
    $('tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').removeClass('highlight');

  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 90%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td:click {
  background-color: blue;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/1.3.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>1234567</th>
    <th>7654321</th>
    <th>5678945</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th><u>22 ounce Dark</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>12count 4oz Dark</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>24count 6oz TJ</u>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td>13587</td>
    <td>2203</td>
    <td>4111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td>14111</td>
    <td>3247</td>
    <td>4332</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td>13212</td>
    <td>3101</td>
    <td>3911</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td>16335</td>
    <td>3299</td>
    <td>4001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td>15421</td>
    <td>3100</td>
    <td>4078</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**  12/22:  Below is my latest JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var old;

$('td').click(function(){

    if ($(this).data().old === undefined) {
        $(this).data({ old: $(this).text() });
    }

    $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);


});

var saveTimeout;

// Remove the "saved" class on keydown
$('td').on('keydown', function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("saved");
});

$('td').on('input blur', function(e) {

    var timeoutDelay=2500;

    if( e.type == "blur"){
        timeoutDelay=1;
    }

    // If NOT already saved...
    if( !$(this).hasClass("saved") ){
        var _this = $(this); // preserve reference to the input field here

        // Add the "saved" class to prevent other saving
        _this.addClass("saved");

        clearTimeout(_this.data('saveTimeout'));
        _this.data('saveTimeout', setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(_this.data().old);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "tester.php",
                data: { 
                    content: _this.text(), 
                    date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
                    prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
                    old: _this.data().old
                }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( msg );
            });

            toastr.options = {
                "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
                "onclick": null,
                "timeOut": "2500",
            }

            toastr.info(_this.data('old'),'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');

            _this.data({});

            _this.prop('contenteditable', false);

        }, timeoutDelay));
    }
});


$("td").hover(function(){



    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings().first().addClass('highlight');

    $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').addClass('highlight');


},function(){



    $(this).removeClass("highlight").siblings().first().removeClass('highlight');

    $('tr:eq(1) th:eq('+$(this).index()+')').removeClass('highlight');


});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for storing the *old* value on the node that it belongs to. Secondly you should make sure not to overwrite an *old* value if you already have one, and only clear it when it is sent to the server.

So remove the *old* variable, and change this:

```
old=$(this).text();
```

To:

```
if ($(this).data().old === undefined) {
    $(this).data({ old: $(this).text() });
}
```

And pass the old value to the server as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "updatedatabase.php",
    data: { 
        content: _this.text(), 
        date: _this.siblings().first().text(),
        prod: $('tr:first-child th:nth-child(' + (_this.index() + 1) + ')').text(),
        old: _this.data().old
    }
})
```

Similarly for toastr:

```
toastr.info(_this.data('old'),'Database Updated!<br><br>Your Previous Amount Was:');
```

Right after that, remove that data, as to indicate it was sent to the server:

```
_this.data().old = undefined;
```

Comment: I am having a strange issue now.  I copy and pasted your code above into the code for the site im working on and it seems as if the old value is no longer making it through ajax because now table values arnt changing.  They changed before, just incorrectly because the wrong # was being sent.  As a test I edited the snippet in my OP and it looks like it might be working correctly there?  possibly something wrong with the `old:` line in ajax?

Comment: Did you try to debug? How about `console.log(_this.data().old)` just before you launch the ajax? What do you get on the server? Did you debug that code and see what arrives there?

Comment: So I changed the ajax call to a test.php file where I just have it print out the post values.  "old" always returns as 0.

Comment: That is half of what I hoped to get from you. Can you give the info for the first half (`console.log` output -- see above)? Can you also provide the PHP code with which you test the received value and add that *in your question*?

Comment: sorry I am still very very new to web design and forgot how console log worked, I believe I got it now though.  On first edit of the `td` it shows 0 like it should have, but once there was an actual number in there and I edit the `td` a second time it still shows old as being 0.

As far as debugging did you mean just trying to check the POST values like I did by changing the ajax landing spot to output the POST values?  

I added the test.php code to the bottom of the OP.

Comment: I am still stuck on this, any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: As you discovered that the value is still reported on the client side as 0 the second time, the problem is not related with ajax or with the server code.  Please specify in your question exactly where in the code you have added `console.log(....)` and mention that the output was 0 twice. I need to see this in context, to be sure what you have (I obviously have no crystal ball and cannot see what you are looking at). It would even be better if you added a section to your question ("Edit: ...") where you put your current JavaScript code, to avoid all doubt.

Comment: I am flowing you with it not being ajax related. I added the EDIT to my main post with my current javascript. I put all of my javascript just to make sure that there wasnt another issue causing this. The console log is the line before ajax.

Comment: Replace `_this.data({});` with `_this.data().old = undefined;`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That fixes the issue!!  Thanks!